# Unknowingly removed gnome and gconf2

Tags: gnome, login

I removed gnome and gconf2 unknowingly and I am unable to login into Ubuntu.Please help me.

Comment: Can you switch to tty1 - ctrl-alt-f1?

Comment: Yes i switched to it

Comment: I login to my system and did the gnome installation and ubuntu session upgrade but still didn't able to go to desktop

Comment: Please reply to this query

Answer (score 3):

As you can log in on a virtual terminal (reachable with Ctrl+Alt+F1) you can

1. re-install the Ubuntu desktop including all its necessary dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
   ```
2. You should now the be able to restart the display manager

   ```
   sudo initctl restart lightdm
   ```

   and switch back to the graphical session with Ctrl+Alt+F7. Alternatively you can reboot Ubuntu.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!